# How to convert several mongo documents to single

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-aggregation

I want to get single document from the entire collection of documents. Let's say I have collection:

```
> db.coll.find({},{_id:0})
{ "field1" : "k1", "field2" : "a", "field3" : "aa" }
{ "field1" : "k2", "field2" : "b", "field3" : "bb" }
{ "field1" : "k3", "field2" : "c", "field3" : "aa" }
{ "field1" : "k4", "field2" : "d", "field3" : "bb" }
{ "field1" : "k5", "field2" : "a", "field3" : "aa" }
{ "field1" : "k6", "field2" : "b", "field3" : "bb" }
{ "field1" : "k7", "field2" : "c", "field3" : "aa" }
{ "field1" : "k8", "field2" : "d", "field3" : "bb" }
```

I need a query, that returns the single document like this:

```
{
"k1": {"field2": "a", "field3": "aa"},
"k2": {"field2": "b", "field3": "bb"},
"k3": {"field2": "c", "field3": "aa"},
"k4": {"field2": "d", "field3": "bb"},
"k5": {"field2": "a", "field3": "aa"},
"k6": {"field2": "b", "field3": "bb"},
"k7": {"field2": "c", "field3": "aa"},
"k8": {"field2": "d", "field3": "bb"}
}
```

Thanks.

My collection is small enough so I can ignore the BSON document limitations.